# ~/.tmux.conf doesn't work when starting but does with "source-file"

Tags: linux, tmux

I want to start tmux with two panes and have one of them running a program:

> [0] [ishpeck@kiyoshi ~]$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
>   split-window -h top
>   [0][ishpeck@kiyoshi ~]$ tmux

When tmux comes up, it displays the error:

> /home/ishpeck/.tmux.conf:1: no current target

With tmux still open, I hit *prefix* then type "*:source ~/.tmux.conf* " and it works as expected.  Why does it never work at start-up, but works fine when I'm sourcing it?

Comment: Can you use a wrapper script like in: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/82yi3s/how_to_get_tmux_to_start_with_a_couple_of_split/?
There's also an explanation why this doesn't work.

Comment: Or how about you do like in an answer in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61386/creating-launchable-tmux-configurations?
Can you then accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now looked at the code for tmux, it appears that the config file is read *before* there is any session.  It's not a trivial to change that.

Based on the comments from Aulis Ronkainen, it looks like the best bet is to have a shell script that runs tmux commands.

See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/82yi3s/how_to_get_tmux_to_start_with_a_couple_of_split/

Comment: I'm glad you solved the issue. Good work!

Answer (score 7):

I figured out a solution that only involves tmux but still involves a second file.

In your tmux.conf add this line:

`set-hook -g after-new-session "source-file /path/to/tmux-windows.conf"`

Then put your windows and splits in that tmux-windows.conf file.